# Add Community custom lightning tabs in SF1 communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, napili, salesforce1-app

I have tried to check this at so many places but the amount of documentation around this seems to be so scattered that I am not getting any data around same,

So I have a Napili template community in which i custom lightning component is present.

Now I have created a custom lightning tab as well to be used in sf1, but now If I go to dropdown for communities, and select the community I can only see standard tabs and nothing custom So is there a way I can add Custom Lightning component tab to Communities in SF1?

Using

> implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable"

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_customize_tabs.htm),

> Lightning Component tabs aren’t supported in Communities.

Comment: I think this line is mentioning about the general community and not the lightning community tab in sf1. right?

Answer (score 0):

Lightning Components tabs are [not yet supported](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_customize_tabs.htm) .The alternative for this would be to use a simple visualforce and create a tab .

Also SF1 on communities have lot of gaps currently requiring user to set my domain which can be not user friendly .

Comment: There is a line in the link that mentions "The tabs that you select also determine community navigation in Salesforce1.". I added the tabs in Manage --> Tabs --> and then my lightning component tab is available there. But on SF1 same community, it does not come. Is it a gap in documentation? or I am doing it wring?

Comment: Thats for VF based communities .And clearly the doc says components tabs are not supported

Comment: The same navigation order seems to control for Napili based templates as well. For me even though the lightning component tabs are not coming, rest of the tabs follow the sequence specified by VF Tabs navigation order, anyways it looks like still there is a lot to be supported in SF1.

Comment: Also can you post the interface that you have on lightning component ?Can you make that as a appHostable and see if that helps

Comment: Already using same - implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable"

Answer (score 0):

You can also try creating a visualforce page/Tab and add your component to that page using lightning:outApp.